# Speed / cost of calling Pubsub directly vs Stackdriver

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-pubsub, stackdriver

To summarize our current setup: we have an AWS server farm which is logging large numbers of text lines to local rotating log files, and a process on each server looks for rotated-out logs and uploads them to Glacier, from which we then download them for processing into a database.

Our plan is to move the servers to GCP, with the servers provide this data to Dataflow and thence filtering it into Bigquery.

The question is, whether we should stream the data into Dataflow, or batch-process it similar to our current process.

As far as I can tell, if we stream it, the options are:

1) Our servers use Stackdriver Logging to write the messages quickly, and we configure Stackdriver to write to Pubsub, and stream from that. Since our servers are currently AWS, this will require Stackdriver Premium and presumably incur costs.

2) Our servers use Pubsub directly.

My questions regarding streaming are:

1) As far as I can tell, Stackdriver Logging doesn't yet have costs for logging, just for each running machine it's being used on. Is that correct? We don't really want to preserve the logs in Stackdriver, just emit them as soon as possible into Pubsub.

2) Using Pubsub directly (Python client) appears to be relatively slow - like, half a second for publishing a single message to a topic. However, batched publishing to a topic is much faster, and it looks like we could get our servers to do that without much trouble. Is it recommended to use Pubsub directly like that, or is it preferred / advantageous for any reason to go via Stackdriver Logging?